# .Net Core 6 ModelState.IsValid Flagged As Not Valid When It Is

Tags: .net, .net-core, foreign-keys, modelstate

When trying to create a new record for USER, ModelState.IsValid is flagged as invalid. However, all the correct data is there.

The issue seems to be in Reference Key.

My Classes

```
   public class Users
   {
    [Key]
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public int IdLOB { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } = default!;
    public string FullName { get; set; } = default!;
    public string? Nickname { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdLOB")]
    public virtual LOBS IdLOBNavigation { get; set; } = default!;
   }

public class LOBS
{
    [Key]
    public int IdLOB { get; set; }
    public string LOB { get; set; } = default!;
    public int? ParentLOB { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Parent LOB")]
    [ForeignKey("ParentLOB")]
    public virtual LOBS? ParentLOBNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

All data is passed to Users, including IdLOB, but it flagged as invalid because of IdLOBNavigation:

[image]

If I jump model validation, the data is processed without error and the record is created. Also, the tables in the database are correct, IdLOBNavigation is a relation and not a field.

**So I believe the error is in how I'm declaring the relation in the Users Class. What is the correct way to do this in .Net 6**

Comment: Adding [ValidateNever] prevents validation. But I'm not sure if this is the correct solution or I'm just patching it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption that you are passing the domain model to an API endpoint and then adding that model to your context and trying to save.

If that is the case, then I think you need to create a request model to take in only the data you need, rather than the actual domain model. You then validate the request model with the limited dataset that you want the end user to be able pass in to be saved. I.e. `IdLOB`, `email`, `fullname`, `nickname`.

That way you limit the end user from being able to set properties they shouldn't (i.e. `ModifiedOn`), can validate your request model explicitly (as we never trust the client) and create a new instance of User (via constructor or mapper like AutoMapper) which is safe to be added to your context.